# Exp:resso Store not returning to correct URL from PayPal

Tags: ee2, expresso-store, ecommerce, paypal, payment-gateway

EE 2.5.3 and Store 1.6.1

I have an issue where it looks like PayPal is not returning the customer to the correct specific Exp:resso Store order confirmation page after successful PayPal Express payment.  This is odd as I tested this installation with no problem, it seems to have just recently started occurring.  It happens with either PayPal account payment or credit/debit card.  The page where it returns the customer to is (wrongly) http://www.example.com/about . The PayPal account 'Auto Return' setting is 'off' as I suspect the return URL should be passed to PayPal by Store.

Here is the EE template code for the final /checkout3 page before transfer to PayPal:

```
{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal"
    return="music/order/ORDER_HASH"
    error_handling="inline"
    payment_method="paypal_express"
    error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'}...
```

Here is the code generated:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/music/checkout3"; method="post" id="" name="" class="form-horizontal" data-order-total="10" >
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline;">
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="music/order/ORDER_HASH" />
<input type="hidden" name="payment_method" value="paypal_express" />
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="20" />
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="music/checkout3" /> ...
```

Thanks a million for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a stray 301 Redirect on /music/order/ in the .htaccess file which was sending the customer back to the wrong page after successful PayPal submission.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the domain to your return_url variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://www.example.com/music/order/ORDER_HASH" />
```

Comment: Thanks MediaGirl - that wasn't necessary as it turned out.  There was a stray 301 Redirect on /music/order/ in the .htaccess file which was sending the customer to the wrong page... doh!

Comment: That will do it! Glad you tracked it down.